# C Проблема с вводом

Tags: c

Ввод в `y2` пропускается при работе. Почему?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    char buffer [5] = {0};
    char y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0;

    printf("Will you use characters (y/n) ?");
    y1 = getchar();

    printf("Will you use big characters (y/n) ?");
    y2 = getchar();

    printf("Will you use numbers (y/n) ?");
    y3 = getchar();

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    printf("%c\r\n", y1);
    printf("%c\r\n", y2);
    printf("%c\r\n", y3);
    printf("%s\r\n", buffer);

    printf("done.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В него считывается нажатие клавиши `<Enter>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    char buffer [5] = {0};
    char y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0;

    printf("Will you use characters (y/n) ?");
    y1 = getchar();
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Will you use big characters (y/n) ?");
    y2 = getchar();
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Will you use numbers (y/n) ?");
    y3 = getchar();
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    printf("%c\r\n", y1);
    printf("%c\r\n", y2);
    printf("%c\r\n", y3);
    printf("%s\r\n", buffer);

    printf("done.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: А как исправить? другую функцию? Я делал с `scanf` тоже самое!

Comment: А я же и привел решение - см. исходник... Мой вариант, кстати, допускает ввод типа `yes`, `no` :) - будет брать только первый символ.

Comment: спасибо! я просто отвлекся)

Answer (score 4):

Функция `getchar` считывает все символы из потока, включая символы пробелов, новой строки и т.д.

Вместо этой функции используйте функцию `scanf`, Например,

```
scanf( " %c", &y1 );
       ^^^^
```

Обратите внимание на пробел перед символом `%`, Он служит для пропуска символов пробелов во входном потоке.

Также при выводе на консоль нет необходимости использовать символ возврата каретки. Достаточно записать

```
printf("%c\n", y1);
        ^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я даже не знал.

Comment: @biggy Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)